# vectorWeights null in Weaviate vector index

Tags: weaviate

Everything is working fine. But I see the vectorWeights null. Are vectors even being used? I did not see any issue while indexing.

http://localhost:8080/v1/objects/055b639d-b9b6-4919-95b4-87a6630fac85

Here is the complete response:

```
{
"class": "Essay",
"creationTimeUnix": 1695684491509,
"id": "055b639d-b9b6-4919-95b4-87a6630fac85",
"lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1695684491509,
"properties": {
"_node_content": "{\"id_\": \"055b639d-b9b6-4919-95b4-87a6630fac85\", \"embedding\": null, \"metadata\": {}, \"excluded_embed_metadata_keys\": [], \"excluded_llm_metadata_keys\": [], \"relationships\": {\"1\": {\"node_id\": \"2a3d5f95-af72-4b6e-8c35-3bc853115295\", \"node_type\": null, \"metadata\": {}, \"hash\": \"4c702b4df575421e1d1af4b1fd50511b226e0c9863dbfffeccb8b689b8448f35\"}, \"2\": {\"node_id\": \"52e8aebf-fbb2-4d59-a7b4-f96445d7eb91\", \"node_type\": null, \"metadata\": {}, \"hash\": \"0f81c5879523cd4dccc71acdb9b42dd538a76e18684ddfcacf5d24060694cd87\"}, \"3\": {\"node_id\": \"082bb795-b7c7-42dd-be12-337d89a1fcae\", \"node_type\": null, \"metadata\": {}, \"hash\": \"91d3db5770b27e3ef24e25e675501d7b03cc41373042916eef8ccc023869ad59\"}}, \"hash\": \"27627775d75745356c52c6ab390f8cc55a076e8099e0b40d5ac82ddd8291a695\", \"text\": \"\", \"start_char_idx\": null, \"end_char_idx\": null, \"text_template\": \"{metadata_str}\\n\\n{content}\", \"metadata_template\": \"{key}: {value}\", \"metadata_seperator\": \"\\n\"}",
"content": "So before we could launch publicly we had to launch privately, in the sense of recruiting an initial set of users and making sure they had decent-looking stores.\n\n[9] We'd had a code editor in Viaweb for users to define their own page styles. They didn't know it, but they were editing Lisp expressions underneath. But this wasn't an app editor, because the code ran when the merchants' sites were generated, not when shoppers visited them.\n\n[10] This was the first instance of what is now a familiar experience, and so was what happened next, when I read the comments and found they were full of angry people. How could I claim that Lisp was better than other languages? Weren't they all Turing complete? People who see the responses to essays I write sometimes tell me how sorry they feel for me, but I'm not exaggerating when I reply that it has always been like this, since the very beginning. It comes with the territory. An essay must tell readers things they don't already know, and some people dislike being told such things.\n\n[11] People put plenty of stuff on the internet in the 90s of course, but putting something online is not the same as publishing it online. Publishing online means you treat the online version as the (or at least a) primary version.\n\n[12] There is a general lesson here that our experience with Y Combinator also teaches: Customs continue to constrain you long after the restrictions that caused them have disappeared. Customary VC practice had once, like the customs about publishing essays, been based on real constraints. Startups had once been much more expensive to start, and proportionally rare. Now they could be cheap and common, but the VCs' customs still reflected the old world, just as customs about writing essays still reflected the constraints of the print era.\n\nWhich in turn implies that people who are independent-minded (i.e. less influenced by custom) will have an advantage in fields affected by rapid change (where customs are more likely to be obsolete).\n\nHere's an interesting point, though: you can't always predict which fields will be affected by rapid change. Obviously software and venture capital will be, but who would have predicted that essay writing would be?\n\n[13] Y Combinator was not the original name. At first we were called Cambridge Seed. But we didn't want a regional name, in case someone copied us in Silicon Valley, so we renamed ourselves after one of the coolest tricks in the lambda calculus, the Y combinator.\n\nI picked orange as our color partly because it's the warmest, and partly because no VC used it. In 2005 all the VCs used staid colors like maroon, navy blue, and forest green, because they were trying to appeal to LPs, not founders. The YC logo itself is an inside joke: the Viaweb logo had been a white V on a red circle, so I made the YC logo a white Y on an orange square.\n\n[14] YC did become a fund for a couple years starting in 2009, because it was getting so big I could no longer afford to fund it personally. But after Heroku got bought we had enough money to go back to being self-funded.\n\n[15] I've never liked the term \"deal flow,\" because it implies that the number of new startups at any given time is fixed. This is not only false, but it's the purpose of YC to falsify it, by causing startups to be founded that would not otherwise have existed.\n\n[16] She reports that they were all different shapes and sizes, because there was a run on air conditioners and she had to get whatever she could, but that they were all heavier than she could carry now.\n\n[17] Another problem with HN was a bizarre edge case that occurs when you both write essays and run a forum. When you run a forum, you're assumed to see if not every conversation, at least every conversation involving you. And when you write essays, people post highly imaginative misinterpretations of them on forums. Individually these two phenomena are tedious but bearable, but the combination is disastrous. You actually have to respond to the misinterpretations, because the assumption that you're present in the conversation means that not responding to any sufficiently upvoted misinterpretation reads as a tacit admission that it's correct. But that in turn encourages more; anyone who wants to pick a fight with you senses that now is their chance.\n\n[18] The worst thing about leaving YC was not working with Jessica anymore. We'd been working on YC almost the whole time we'd known each other, and we'd neither tried nor wanted to separate it from our personal lives, so leaving was like pulling up a deeply rooted tree.",
"doc_id": "2a3d5f95-af72-4b6e-8c35-3bc853115295",
"document_id": "2a3d5f95-af72-4b6e-8c35-3bc853115295",
"ref_doc_id": "2a3d5f95-af72-4b6e-8c35-3bc853115295"
},
"vectorWeights": null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `include=vector` as a parameter:

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/objects/055b639d-b9b6-4919-95b4-87a6630fac85?include=vector
```

See available RESTful params [here](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/rest/objects#url-parameters)